# VMDK backup file content changes when I rollback to a history snapshot

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I have a virtual machine `ubuntu20.04` with 20G disk(disk1). And I add another 50G disk(disk2) to `ubuntu20.04`. When VMWare let me name the new 50G disk, I name it `50G` to reduce my misreading because the default name is suffixed with `-001` and so on, which make me always confused about which vmdk files are matched with my new disk device.
With the two disks installed, I took a snapshot `state-original`. 
After making some modifications to disk2, I backup the vmdk files which have string `50G` because I want to use disk2 of new state in another virtual machine, and then rollback to `state-original`.
But when I add the backup vmdk files of disk2 to another virtual machine `ubuntu18.04`, I just found its content is the same as it in the `state-original` state. 
I want to know what happened? Do the changes to original files can take effect to the backup files?

A picture to make the procedure clearer.
1,2,3,4 means the order of things I've done.

[image]

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. I am very familiar with VMWare but even I am confused by this question

Comment: @Ramhound OK I'm sorry, I've added some details and a picture to clarify the problem.

Comment: You seen ti have copied the disk without its snapshots. Which files have you renamed? Are you aware that a disk with snapshots is spread over several files?

Comment: Also remember that VMware Snapshots are for making changes and committing the changes, not backups.  You need to copy to / rename to what they were when VMware made them.

Comment: Which product are you using?  Exactly what did you do to add disk2 to the second virtual machine?  Which `.vmdk` file did you add?  If you added only the base disk and not the leaf disk, then the second VM would not be using the new state of the virtual disk.

Comment: @harrymc sorry, I'm not a native speaker, what do you mean "ti" in the sentence "You seen ti have copied the disk without its snapshots."? I didn't rename any files, I just copy them to "backup" them (I know it's not actual backup now) . Does "a disk with snapshots is spread over several files" mean "Hard disk stored in multiple files"? or do you mean the behavior I encountered only occurs in the situation "Hard disk stored in multiple files"? besides that I realized even though I didn't rollback I would also find the disk in the snapshot's state. I guess should learn more about snapshot.

Comment: @John thanks for comment. Does "copy to / rename to what they were when VMware made them" mean copy vmdk files to `/` directory? Does the `cp`'s destination matter? And what should I rename to? For example my VM1 is called `ubuntu20.04` with the disk2 whose name is `ubuntu20.04-40G.vmdk` when it's created, VM2 is called  "ubuntu16.04", and I choose the mode `Hard disk stored in multiple files`, what should rename them to?

Comment: @jamesdlin thanks for comment. I'm using VMWare Workstation 15 Pro. I choose the mode `Hard disk stored in multiple files` and I choose `ubuntu20.04-50G.vmdk` file ,whose size is less than 1 MB and can be viewed by notepad saying `Disk DescriptorFile`, to add. How should I find the leaf disk to use the new state of the virtal disk?

Comment: When you take a snapshot, you'll end up with a file named something like `ubuntu20.04-50G-######.vmdk`.  Use that one. (Don't confuse this with the files named `...-s###.vmdk`; those are separate parts of the disk ("disk extents") from using split disks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMware Workstation and Player use the following naming scheme for virtual disk (`.vmdk`) files:

`VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME-XXXXXX-sYYY.vmdk`

where `VIRTUAL_MACHINE_NAME` is the name of the virtual machine (at the time of creation), `XXXXXX` is the delta disk number, and `YYY` identifies the "disk extent" (a segment of the disk when splitting a virtual disk across multiple files).

As a concrete example, consider the following set of `.vmdk` files:

```
Windows10.vmdk
Windows10-s001.vmdk
Windows10-s002.vmdk
Windows10-s003.vmdk
Windows10-000002.vmdk
Windows10-000002-s001.vmdk
Windows10-000002-s002.vmdk
Windows10-000002-s003.vmdk
```

Here I have disk files for a VM named "Windows10".  The presence of the `-s###` files indicates that the VM uses split disks, and the disk is split into 3 parts.  The `.vmdk` files without the `-s###` suffix are disk *descriptor* files; they contain metadata for the split disk and are very small text files.  `Windows10.vmdk` is the disk descriptor that corresponds to the `Windows10-s###.vmdk` files. `Windows10-000002.vmdk` is the disk descriptor for the `Windows10-000002-s###.vmdk` files. (And, of course, if you use monolithic disks instead of split disks, there won't be separate disk descriptor and disk extent files; they'll be combined into a single `.vmdk` file.)

The presence of `Windows10-000002.vmdk` indicates that a snapshot was taken of the VM.  `Windows10.vmdk` (and its corresponding extents) is the *base* disk; it stores the state of the VM's disk when the snapshot was taken.  `Windows10-00002.vmdk` (and its corresponding disk extents) are *delta disks* that store changes from the previous disk (which in this case is the base disk, but there can be a chain of delta disks if you take multiple snapshots).  Modifying any non-leaf disks will corrupt all disks later in the chain, so non-leaf disks should be treated as immutable.

When you add a virtual disk to another VM, you should:

- Select the disk descriptor file, never the disk extent (`-s###`) files.
- Select only a leaf `.vmdk` file.  Typically (but not always) this will be the highest delta disk number.  If you have multiple snapshots, you can check VM Settings > Hard Disk to see the filename of the current virtual disk being written to.